# Submit check boxes doesn't reach as array to php

Tags: forms, zend-framework, checkbox

I want to submit a form that have many checkboxes with different values, using firebug I am sure that the checkboxes values are send to the server, but when I print_r the values of the post variable, only the last value is printed and igoring the other values.

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruits" value="apple" />
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruits" value="orange" />
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruits" value="banana" />
```

and in the server when I print the request parameters

```
   $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    print_r($formData);
```

Only the last option is printed even I choose all of them and firebug shows them all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve it by making [] in the name of the checkboxex

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruits[]" value="apple" />
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruits[]" value="orange" />
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruits[]" value="banana" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ZF way of doing the same

```
   $fruits = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('fruits', array(
        'multiOptions' => array(
            'apple' => 'Label for apple',
            'orange' => 'I am good orange',
            'banana' => 'I am banana'
        );
    ));

    echo $fruits;
```